# NDSI handling of areas that cross over a pixel

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, landsat-8, pixel, calculate-values

I am using GEE to calculate the NDSI on Landsat8 using a polygon area of 500m.
Since Landsat8 has a 30m pixel resolution, I wondered how the partial pixels are handled in the calculations.

Are they included or excluded from the area? Will I have a 480mx480m or a 510mx510m pixel area?

My area of study is 500m due to me having to make a MODIS area comparison.

Answer (score 1):

When you clip to a geometry, your pixels get masked:

- For pixels completely outside the geometry, the mask value is `0`.
- For pixels completely inside the geometry, the mask value is `1`.
- For pixels on the border will get a fractional value based on the fraction of the pixel that is inside the geometry.

When you do a reduce region with a reducer like `ee.Reducer.sum()`, it will be default be *weighted*. That is, a pixel with value `12` and a mask of `0.75` will add `12 * 0.75 = 9` to the sum. That's why you still can get a reasonably accurate area, even if your scale is large.

Comment: So, in NDSI, the pixels at the border would get a "half value"? let's say that a pixel that is on the border is 50% outside the study area. Does that mean if the NDSI value of that pixel is 1, the final NDSI value of that pixel would be 1*0.5 = 0.5?

Comment: Not in general. When you reduce the pixels over the area, using a weighted reducer, 0.5 would be used for that pixel.